# C# Convert Func<T1, object> to Func<T1, T2>

Tags: c#, generics, lambda

I have no doubt this is as easy to do as possible, but I have a function creator library that creates lambda functions for me of the form:

```
Func<T1, object>
```

And I'm looking to specify the out parameter more specifically - Basically, I'm looking to be able to create something along the lines of:

```
private Func<T1, T2> GetFunc<T1, T2>(string expression)
{
    Func<T1, object> objFunc = CreateFunction(expression));
    return objFunc as Func<T1, T2>;
}
```

But, when I try this, I get back a `null` (as an aside, if I return `objFunc` as a `Func<T1, object>` it is not a null, so I know that's not where my issue lay).

How do I do this correctly?

Comment: Side note: If you want to cast, then cast (i.e. `(Func<T1, T2>)objFunc`). Don't use `as`, unless you have a good reason to do so. That way, your statement will fail quickly with an `InvalidCastException` and you don't have to track `NullReferenceException`s and "check whether the value was null before to know whether the cast failed or not".

Comment: Doing this correctly would involve not using the function creation library that does such unsound things. The problem is in that library.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try:

```
private Func<T1, T2> GetFunc<T1, T2>(string expression)
{
    Func<T1, object> objFunc = CreateFunction(expression));
    return arg=>(T2)objFunc(arg);
}
```

Comment: DARN IT!!! - I was so close!!!! - I tried 2 inputs for the return statement, that makes perfect sense!! - THANK YOU!!!!!

Answer (score 10):

Would it work to simply wrap your existing function call in another one that performs a cast on the returned value?

```
return t1 => (T2)objFunc(t1);
```

Comment: Thank you!!! - That's EXACTLY what I needed!!!! - Tyree just beat you to it, but I can't thank you enough for the answer!!!!